# How to prepend default endpoint to Angular $http requests?

Tags: angularjs, http, gruntjs

I have an Angular application that gets some variables from an environment file. I change the content of this environment file with Grunt. After the grunt task run, I have a variable defined in environment.js, `var envBaseUrl = 'https://live.example.com';`

I would like to set default base URL for http requests based on the env file.

One approach that I used before is creating a constant, then manually add it to each $http URL for example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.constant('BASE_URL', envBaseUrl || 'http://dev.example.com');
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, BASE_URL) {
    $http.get(BASE_URL + '/someUrl').success(function(data, status, headers, config) { /* :) */ }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) { /* :( */ });
});
```

My problem with this approach is that I need to inject the `BASE_URL` constant and manually add to each `$http`.

I was searching for something like the following, but I didn't succeed:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequests.push(prependBaseUrl);
});
```

Comment: I cannot think of anything simple, but a request interceptor can do this easily. See documentation on `$http`

Answer (score 1):

I used interceptors, as recommended by Chandermani:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function(){
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      // prepend base url
      config.url = BASE_URL + config.url;
      return config;
    }
  };
});
```

However, this can be tricky if you use plugins, frameworks (for example: Angular UI Router, JS Data, OAuth) providers and configs in your application, so to solve that I needed to add more logic to the interceptors, then I asked myself, isn't `$http.get(BASE_URL + '/someUrl')` easier in the 5 cases I need them?

If I find a better solution, I'll update my post.